# How to change property of Instantiated component in react?

Tags: reactjs

Given the following code:

```
    export const AdmButton = ({icon,title,iconSize}) =>{
        return({icon} {title})
```

---

```
    buttondata.map((el, index) => {
     <AdmButton title={el.title} icon={el.icon} iconSize="3em"/>
    })
```

---

```
export const buttondata=[{
            title:'calc',
            icon: <ImIcons.ImCalculator size="2em"/>,
        },*/.../*
]
```

The `AdmButton` is by iteration created as many times as objects in `buttondata`. The object contains as icon the component from react-icons, in the example `ImIcons.ImCalculator` is being used. Now, this component has a property called `size` which I'd like to change depending the place the button is shown, but I don't find a way to refer to `size` (or another property) when the component is being called via object property. What's the right way to modify or overwrite a Property of a given component iterated this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of being a hard-coded component, the `icon` property in your object can be a function which generates a component.  And that function can accept an argument:

```
icon: (size) => <ImIcons.ImCalculator size={size} />
```

Then in your `AdmButton` component you can invoke that function with the parameter:

```
return({icon(iconSize)} {title})
```

So each iteration when mapping will pass the parameter along and instantiate the icon on the fly.

---

Side note: Your call to `.map()` is missing the `return` in the callback, and as such currently won't render anything.  Either include a `return` or remove the curly braces to make use of an implicit return.

Comment: I tried your solution, however I get the following error:
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: @Germán: Where specifically are you rendering a function?  Can you show the updated code and specify the exact element referenced by the error?

Comment: Your response worked, however, I have a follow-up problem. I've been trying to solve it with no success, in any case, thanks for helping me with this issue!!